# How do you surpress a new tab opening when running a SAS Stored Process on SAS Web Services?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, sas, ods, sas-stored-process

I'm building a web application using react/nodejs for my front end and SAS for my back end. I have a SAS stored process tested and working and registered. The stored process uses `ods excel file=_webout;` to send back an excel file from a SAS process.

Where I'm at now is when I hit the button to navigate to the SAS Stored process, it will open a new tab in the browser and then the window closes and then the downloads menu is displayed asking the user what to do with the file. I find this clunky. My code for the button click is basically:

```
href={`xxxxxx_server_link_xxxxx/SAS_STORED_PROC&Param1=....}}`}
    target="_blank"
```

What I'd like to happen is to make the process seamless for the user. What I'd like to happen is User clicks button nothing appears to happen (no page navigation or popups).. then the downloads menu appears when it's done. iow, all action to execute the SAS stored process is hidden from the user.

And for some reason, I get the big download menu instead of the one that I'm used to in the top right of the browser window. Is this also something I have control over? or no?

how do I do this?   I've tagged 'ajax' but I'm not sure if that's the solution.

Comment: Why tell it to open in a new window, `_blank`, if that is not what you want?  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: What I found is that without target equals blank, there is no new window; however, the webpage (current tab) will close, which is annoying and not what I want. using target =_blank was to prevent the page from closing.

Comment: Agree you don't want `target=_blank`.  Are you using STPSRV_HEADER() to set the content disposition in the header to attachment? Something like `data _null_; rc = stpsrv_header('Content-type','application/vnd.ms-excel'); rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition',"attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");run;`  It's possible you can't use %STPBEGIN() with this approach.

Comment: yes. i am using the data _null_ headers as described. I actually didnt include any stored proc macro code in my SP. so i do not have %spbegin.